# Searching for partial match - 1 item to be searched in $n$ preprocessed items

Tags: co.combinatorics

My problem is generalization of the simple problem:

Search for item $x$ in a set $S$.

This is trivial to do it fast if the elements are comparable. Sort the $S$, and do the binary search.

My problem is that I'm interested in partial match. That is, my items are ordered sets of $n = 15$ numbers, and I consider them equal if they have $m = 10$ numbers (at same position) same. For smaller numbers (like 5 out of 6), I can use $n = 6$ sorted sets that have all $m = 5$ number subsets of preprocessed items and then just do 6 binary searches. But for large numbers $n$ and $m$ where $n - m > 2$ number of sets (the binomial coefficient) explodes.

Is there efficient way to search for a partial match?

The only thing that I could think of is to index each number of the set. For example, when preprocessing size 3 sets:

```
{1,2,3},//set0
{2,3,4}//set1
```

Create entries

```
1->(set0,pos0)(position is important), 2->(set0,pos1),(set1,pos0) ... (4->set1,pos2)
```

and then when I get a new number, I just go for the each number in it and check the sets in which it appears. If there is a set that has many hits (say 10 or more), they are declared the same.

Of course I could use an array trick (i.e. array[1234] contains the pointer to the list of sets that contain 1234). This works for small ranges. For large ranges, I could hash the number and do modulo.

Of course this could go very very wrong for some distributions of preprocessed data.

So is there a better way?

Comment: I just edited your question to improve the presentation. (The edit will be visible after someone with enough rep approves it.) Please check that I didn't introduce any errors.

Comment: Tnx, it didnt introduce any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a better way is to include the position in the key of the entries; in your example you'll have:

```
(1,pos0)->{set0}
(2,pos0)->{set1}
(2,pos1)->{set0}
(3,pos1)->{set1}
(3,pos2)->{set0}
(4,pos2)->{set1}
```

When you must search for an item (an ordered set) $(n_1,n_2,...,n_{15})$, you can perform the union of the sets associated to the keys $(n_1,pos0), ..., (n_{15},pos14)$, keeping track of the number of hits for each set. From the union you can finally extract the set (or sets) with 10 or more hits.

If this is a real problem with thousands of entries, a good RDBMS (such as MySQL) will handle the data (and searches) efficiently.

If you need to keep everything in memory, you can use an hash table to store the key,values $(n_i,pos_j) \rightarrow \{set_1,...,set_k\}$

Addendum: your problem resembles the classical problem of efficiently storing and searching word co-occurrences using *[inverted indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)* (*Information Retrieval* area)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the problem correctly, this looks like an instance of the [Nearest Neighbor Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search), under the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

In other words, the "distance" between ordered sets is just the number of mismatched positions. The goal is to preprocess a collection (dataset) of ordered sets, each of size n, so that given a "query" ordered set, the data structure reports an ordered set within Hamming distance n-m. In your case, n is the dimension, and n-m is the distance. (This variant is actually called *near* neighbor search (the *nearest* neighbor is one where one reports the closest dataset item).

If that's the problem, then the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) may be a good start for pointers on existing work.